# Need assistance with computing the following two questions concerning change of variable in multi-variable calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having difficulties setting up the correct change of variable for the following two questions.  I am wondering if someone can offer me assistance.

1) Let $\ n > 0$, Compute the integral

$$\iint_\Omega \ (x+y)^n \,dx\,dy$$

where $\Omega=\{(x,y): x\geq 0,\ y\geq 0, x+y \leq 1\}$

2) Evaluate the integral

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}} \,dy\,dx$$

using the transformation $\ x=u, y=uv\ $

For the first question, I tried

$$\frac{1} {2} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{-v}^{v} {v}^{n}\ du\ dv,\ $$ with $\ u=x-y,\ v=x+y\ $ but I don't seem to be getting the correct answer.  The textbook solution is $\frac{1} {6(n+4)}\ $

For the second question, I figured the original is a triangular region with an area $\frac{1} {2}\ $, so when applying a change of variable, the transformed region should also have the same area.  I tried with the following transformation:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{\frac{1} {v}}^{1} \ v\sqrt{{u}^{2}+{(uv)}^{2}}\ du\ dv\ $$

However, I got the wrong answer.  The textbook solution is $\frac{1} {6}\ [\sqrt{2}+log(1+\sqrt{2})] \ $

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe there is a typo in your textbook. I think the answer to the first problem is $\frac{1}{n+2}$. Even Wolfram Alpha agrees: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+(x%2By)%5En;+0+%3C+x+%3C+1;+0+%3C+y+%3C+1-x;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For number 1, I don't get the answer in the book.  I have $$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-y} {(x+y)^n}\ dx\ dy=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{u}^{1} {v^n\ du\ dv}$$ using the transformation, $u=x, v=x+y$ which has Jacobian determinant $1$.  Evaluating the integral gives $\frac{1}{n+2}.$  This is the same answer I get from [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20(x%2By)%5En%20dx%20dy,%20y%200%20to%201,%20x%200%20to%201-y%20).

Comment: Please reformat your comment so I can read it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for my initial reply.  I am still new to LaTex..  Anyways,I got the question from the text: Functions of several real variables by Martin Moskowitz and Fotios Paliogiannis.  I am not sure if the book's solution is wrong.  The text used another question as another example:

Compute the integral

$$\iint_\Omega \ {e}^{\frac{(y-x)} {(y+x)}} \,dx\,dy \ $$ 

where $\Omega=\{(x,y): x\geq 0,\ y\geq 0, x+y \leq 1\}\ $

I just used the same limits of integration from that question which is the same as what I used.  But I got the wrong answer.  :(

Comment: So it must be a coincidence that Nick and I and Wolfram Alpha all got the same answer?

Comment: Is the first question really need the change of variable technique, or is it just plain Fubini's theorem?  Because I don't see what transformation I can use for change of variable.